# Why does the status "under peer review" change to "Awaiting Reviewer selection" after 2 months?

Tags: publications

I submitted my manuscript 3 months back. After a few days, the status changed to "under peer review". It was so for two months. Now the status is changed to "awaiting reviewer selection". It is totally confusing. what does this really mean? what is happening to my manuscript?

Answer (score 1):

They might simply look for an additional reviewer. Sometimes this happens, e.g. if the editor couldn't make a decision based on the reports of the two initial reviewers. You could also write to the editor and ask what is going on.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. But its since 3 months of submitting my manuscript and 2 months of "under peer review" process. Also there is no answer for any inquiry mail sent.

Comment: A first round of peer review might take up to 8 weeks easily and finding reviewers also needs time. So if the editor started to search for an additional reviewer after receiving the first two reviewer reports, everything seems quite in time. If you wanna know in detail what is going on, the only option you have, is to e-mail the editor.